# Introduce react element in a string

Tags: reactjs

I've got locale content for a website coming as a prop which is a string value and I want to replace something in it with a react element. But when I do it the like using the replace function, the element is converted to a string and I see `[object Object]` in the output for the replaced part instead of the react element being rendered. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: You can, but you should show us some code, see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet would do the job, and is flexible enough to serve your needs. Also tackles the case where you MIGHT want to exchange MULTIPLE parts of the string with the custom_component.

```
const localeString = "Locale content replace_me_with_component and some text at the end";

const renderCustomComponent = () => <div>this is the custom component to include in the string</div>

const App = ({ localeString, ...props }) => {
    const splittedArrayOfStrings = localeString.split("replace_me_with_component");

    // You might want to add validations, in case the localeString does not contain your "special" string in it (replace_me_with_component)

    return splittedArrayOfStrings.map((string, index) => {
        // Inject the custom component into the string
        if (index < separatedArrayOfStrings.length - 1) {
            return (<>{string} {renderCustomComponent()}</>)
        }

        return <>{string}</>
    })
}

// Call the App component
<App localeString={localeString} />
```

Comment: For my useCase I temporarily used `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but I think it would be better to write a function to handle the content the way you have mentioned. Thanks